# TeamCity build - VCS trigger/Branch specification not working as intended

Tags: git, build, branch, teamcity

I have a Git repository with 3 classic branches (dev, staging, master).
I'm trying to setup a VCS in TeamCity 8.1.x, so that a build triggers only when a push is made to a specific subfolder in the repository.

Example:
Under the dev branch, I have 2 folders:

```
(dev)
- ServiceAPI/
- ServiceAPI.Test/
```

Now, I want TeamCity **only to trigger a build when I push a change in the ServiceAPI folder, not the other one** (ServiceWeb.Test).

I have tried to setup a few different configs (I figured this could be done using *Branch Specification*, but it doesn't work, or I'm doing it wrong).

In the VCS configuration I have:
*Default branch* set as **dev**
*Branch specification* set as **+:refs/heads/dev/ServiceAPI/***

Assuming that the *Default branch* is always active,
I tried adding **-:refs/heads/dev/*** in the *Branch specification* to cancel it out, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to put a different branch than **dev** in *Default branch*, but then the trigger didn't work when pushing changes in the **dev** branch, regardless what is in *Branch specification*.

Then I tried excluding the **ServiceApi.Test** folder by inserting **-:refs/heads/dev/ServiceAPI.Test/*** to *Branch specification*, but that didn't work either. TeamCity builds when I push changes into either folder.

I hope I'm explaining the problem well enough. Please let me know if you need more information.
Any ideas would be most welcome.

Regards,
Gunnar

---

**Updated:** This issue was resolved, but I can't remember how exactly and I'm too lazy to check it out. If however, someone encounters this and can't figure it out, feel free to let me know and I can most likely reproduce the problem and have a detailed answer if needed.

Answer (score 2):

@Gunnar, there is another way of doing it. You can create a Build Trigger,specifically a VCS Trigger,  that will ignore any changes in your exclusive path. These work in the syntax of Ant-like wildCards. So you can create a trigger that says , run only for changes in ServiceAPI/ or one that runs for anything except  ServiceAPI.Test/.

The syntax would be +:ServiceAPI/** or -:ServiceAPI/**.

PS:Also note that your default branch to monitor is different from the trigger conditions.

Answer (score 1):

@Gunnar, try adding both the + and - variations and see if it works. There are times when teamcity gets confused if you add a exclusivity operator.

```
-:refs/heads/dev/* 
-:refs/heads/dev/ServiceAPI.Test/*
```

Also, parameterize your GIT repo name so that you can pass in your branch name (that is to be monitored) as a parameter. IT will help in  reducing the time it takes Teamcity to scan larger repo's

@Gunnar, by parameterizing I mean this:
In your GiT repo setup in teamctity, for the default branch input , put in a parameter for ex %branch.name%. In your build target, if you mention the name of your branch using the parameter %branch.name%, it will only monitor the branch/ path that you are giving using the parameter . For ex if you give the param as develop in your build target , it will monitor only develop branch .

Once you do that, your exclusivity operator changes to

```
-:ServiceAPI.Test/*
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and other +|- combinations. TC doesn't seem to ignore these if the "Default branch" already is watching the "dev" branch. But what you are saying is that some form of combination like this should work, is that right? Also, I don't know what you mean by "parameterize my Git repo name" :)